# sql results different tables.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my table for this query. I need to find a way that all table result will combine in one table.

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
   ACCT_NR VARCHAR(30)
 , DEDNCODE VARCHAR(30)
 , DEDN_ALPHA VARCHAR(12)
 , AMOUNT DECIMAL(10,2)
 , AGING INT
 , PAY_PERIOD CHAR(6)
 , [TYPE] CHAR(1)
 )


INSERT INTO #temp (ACCT_NR, DEDNCODE, DEDN_ALPHA, AMOUNT, AGING, PAY_PERIOD, [TYPE])
VALUES 
 ('20110101401', '159', 'MEM PLAN', 16.00  , 0, '012013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '557', 'PHILHEALTH', 175.00 , 0, '012013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '617', 'S G T I', 6.00   , 0, '012013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '634', 'PAGIBIG C', 100.00 , 0, '012013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '761', 'PSMBFI EP', 445.02 , 0, '012013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '762', 'PSMBFI BG', 25.00  , 0, '012013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '009', 'PSSLAI', 2000.00, 0, '012013', 'N'),
 ('20110101401', '350', 'W TAX', 786.80 , 0, '012013', 'N'),
 ('20110101401', '551', 'AFPMBA ADDL', 1054.90, 0, '012013', 'N'),
 ('20110101401', '768', 'PSMBFI EL', 3277.78, 7, '012013', 'N')

 INSERT INTO #temp (ACCT_NR, DEDNCODE, DEDN_ALPHA, AMOUNT, AGING, PAY_PERIOD, [TYPE])
 VALUES 
 ('20110101401', '159', 'MEM PLAN', 16.00  , 0, '022013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '557', 'PHILHEALTH', 175.00 , 0, '022013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '617', 'S G T I', 6.00   , 0, '022013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '634', 'PAGIBIG C', 100.00 , 0, '022013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '761', 'PSMBFI EP', 445.02 , 0, '022013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '762', 'PSMBFI BG', 25.00  , 0, '022013', 'S'),
 ('20110101401', '009', 'PSSLAI', 2000.00, 0, '022013', 'N'),
 ('20110101401', '350', 'W TAX', 786.80 , 0, '022013', 'N'),
 ('20110101401', '551', 'AFPMBA ADDL', 1054.90, 0, '022013', 'N'),
 ('20110101401', '768', 'PSMBFI EL', 3277.78, 7, '022013', 'N')
```

And this is my code that generates the result that gives me many tables

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @acctnr NVARCHAR(MAX),
@payperiod NVARCHAR(MAX),
@payperiod2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @acctnr = '19991200184';
SET @payperiod = '012013';
SET @payperiod2= '052013';

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(p.DEDN_ALPHA) 
                from #temp p
               where ACCT_NR = @acctnr

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

while CONVERT(int,@payperiod) <= CONVERT(int,@payperiod2)
begin

     set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
         (

            SELECT AMOUNT, DEDN_ALPHA
     FROM #temp
       where ACCT_NR = Cast((' + @acctnr + ') As nvarchar(30)) and PAY_PERIOD = ' + @payperiod + '

        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            min(amount)
            for DEDN_ALPHA in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

    execute(@query)

    set @payperiod = '0' + CONVERT(nvarchar, convert(int,@payperiod) + 10000)
    set @payperiod = REPLACE(STR(@payperiod, 6), SPACE(1), '0')
    end
```

The problem is that the result gives me many tables.
How can I make that all the results will be in one table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why did you give me downvotes? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @acctnr NVARCHAR(MAX),
@payperiod NVARCHAR(MAX),
@payperiod2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @acctnr = '20110101401';
SET @payperiod = '012013';
SET @payperiod2= '052013';

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(p.DEDN_ALPHA) 
            from #temp p
           where ACCT_NR = @acctnr

    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')


set @query = 'select * from 
(
select dense_rank() over( order by pay_period) rw ,dedn_alpha,amount from #temp 
where ACCT_NR= '+@acctnr+' 
      and cast(PAY_PERIOD as int)
           between CONVERT(int,'+@payperiod+') and CONVERT(int,'+@payperiod2+')
) a
pivot 
(
max(amount)
for dedn_alpha in(' + @cols + ')
)pvt'

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Hi ravi sorry for the late reply.. yes in someways this helps.. but those pivots are dynamic so i can't do what you do in this code

        for dedn_alpha in([AFPMBA ADDL],[MEM PLAN],[PAGIBIG C],[PHILHEALTH],[PSMBFI BG]
               ,[PSMBFI EL],[PSMBFI EP],[PSSLAI],[S G T I],[W TAX])

Comment: @RenzPhilipSantos : It can easily be made dynamic.Check update.

Comment: yes.. i made that kind of changes.. and thanks for the reply again :)
BTW do you know something about crystal report? because i need to populate this on a report.. which is dynamic report with dynamic query..

Comment: one more thing your new code give's me error 
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@payperiod".